Show that $ 2^{1-t} \leq \frac{\exp(-t/2)}{1 - \exp(-t/2)}$ for $t > 0$

Let $t > 0$. I am attempting to cleverly prove that:
$$
2^{1-t} \leq \frac{\exp(-t/2)}{1 - \exp(-t/2)}.
$$

I started by observing that the term on the right-hand side can be rewritten as:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \exp(-tk/2),
$$
and I obtained:
$$
2^{1-t} \leq \frac{\exp(-(t-1)/2)}{1 - \exp(-(t-1)/2)}.
$$
Unfortunately, this bound is larger than the term on the right-hand side of the original inequality. This suggests that my initial approach involved an overly crude majorization. Refining this step might help achieve the desired result.

The desired inequality is written as
$$2\mathrm{e}^{- (t/6) \times 6\ln 2} \le \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-t/2}}{1 - \mathrm{e}^{-t/2}}.$$
Since $6\ln 2 > 4$, it suffices to prove that
$$2\mathrm{e}^{- (t/6) \times 4} \le \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-t/2}}{1 - \mathrm{e}^{-t/2}}.$$
Let $u := \mathrm{e}^{-t/6} \in (0, 1)$. It suffices to prove that, for all $0 < u < 1$,
$$2 u^4 \le \frac{u^3}{1 - u^3},$$
or
$$2u^4 - 2u + 1 \ge 0$$
which is true since $u^4 + u^4 + \frac16 \times 6
\ge 8\sqrt[8]{u^4 \cdot u^4 \cdot (1/6)^6} \ge 2u$. We are done.

The given inequality is equivalent to
$$
2^{t-1} \ge e^{t/2}-1.
$$
Consider the difference
$$f(t) = 2^{t-1} -e^{t/2}+1,$$
for $t\ge 0$. Its derivative
$$f’(t) = (\ln 2) 2^{t-1} -\frac12 e^{t/2},$$
vanishes at
$$t_0= -\frac{2\ln\ln2}{2\ln2-1}.$$
It is easy to see that $t_0>0$. What’s more nontrivial is that $t_0<2$, which follows from $e<4\ln2$:
$$
4\ln 2 = 4 \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}k > 4 \sum_{k=1}^{100} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}k > \left(1-\frac1{100}\right)^{-100} > e,
$$
where the second inequality can be verified in a CAS and the third inequality follows from $e< (1-1/x)^{-x}$ for all $x>1$.
Now, we have
$$
f(t_0) = 1-\left(\frac{2\ln2-1}{2\ln2}\right)e^{t_0/2} > 1-\left(\frac{2\ln2-1}{2\ln2}\right) e >0,
$$
which follows from
$$
\frac1e + \frac1{2\ln2} > \sqrt{\frac2{e\ln 2}} >1,
$$
where the first inequality is AM-GM inequality and the second inequality follows from $\ln 2 < 2e^{-1}$:
$$
\ln 2 = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k} < \sum_{k=1}^{51}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k} < 2\left( 1-\frac1{51} \right)^{51} < \frac2e,
$$
where the second inequality can be verified in a CAS and the third inequality follows from $e^{-1} > (1-1/x)^x$ for $x>1$.
